# SQL Query to compare two tables for names

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I am building a SQL query which compares two tables A and B by a [name] column and returns the names from table A that are not in table B

Example

```
Table A

ID Name Address 
1  A    ABC
2  B    XYZ
3  C    PQR

Table B
ID Name Gender 
1  A    F
2  B    M
3  D    F
```

The query I wrote should return third row from table A as it is not in table B and should exclude all other rows

Following is the query I built

```
Select * from A oa left join B gp ON oa.name!=gp.name
```

the above doesn't return the results I was expecting. 
Can this be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
select * from A where name not in (select name from B)
```

Better way:

```
select * from A where not exists (select 1 from B where B.name = A.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

"A left join B" means keeping everything in A, and associating records in B if the condition is satisfied.

In your case, if you really wanna use left join, here is what it should be ('=', not '!='):

`Select * from A oa left join B gp ON oa.name=gp.name where gp.name is null`

Better way would be using 'not exists' performance-wise, or 'except' if null values are not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using excpet operator will help

```
 select * from TableA
    except
    select * from TableB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b
ON a.name = b.name
WHERE b.name IS NULL
```